# How to encrypt and decrypt String with my passphrase in Java (Pc not mobile platform)?

Tags: java, encryption

I want to encrypt a string and then put it on a file. Also want to decrypt it when I want.  I don’t need very strong security. I just want to make it harder to get my data others.

I tried several ways. Here are these.

Md5 Encryption:

[How to hash a string in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934331/android-how-to-encrypt-a-string#)

```
public static final String md5(final String toEncrypt) {
        try {
            final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
            digest.update(toEncrypt.getBytes());
            final byte[] bytes = digest.digest();
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytes[i]));
            }
            return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            return ""; // Impossibru!
        }
    }
```

I tried this function and able to encrypt a string but I can’t decrypt data from it. So it is not the solution.

DES Encryption:

[Encrypt and decrypt a String in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487525/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-java)

Here passphrase is Auto generated. Is always passphrase will same on all time? Then where is my security. So it is not my solution too.

AES Encryption:

[How do I encrypt/decrypt a string with another string as a password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762771/how-do-i-encrypt-decrypt-a-string-with-another-string-as-a-password)

I also tried Aes from this link. Here key is also auto generated?

Is there any other way?

Comment: Or check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8828196/589259) if you want to store a key in your application instead of a password, the one created by Erickson uses PBKDF2, which is useful to convert passwords to keys, but it is really slow.

Comment: **WARNING** I've upvoted one question which sat there at 0 points, all the other answers up to 2020-03 are completely and utterly insecure. Don't use copy / paste security, as it doesn't exist. You need to learn the basics of cryptography to apply it or to determine if solutions are valid.

Answer (score 66):

```
package com.example;
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
public class StrongAES 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            String text = "Hello World";
            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
            // Create key and cipher
            Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // encrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
            System.err.println(new String(encrypted));
            // decrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(encrypted));
            System.err.println(decrypted);
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StrongAES app = new StrongAES();
        app.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that the asker can understand the solution.

Comment: You will get a special character in the encrypted message.  Use encoding to avoid if required.

Comment: How to pass initialization vector ?

Comment: @Vignesh When using large string the decryption returns an empty string only

Comment: @Vignesh +1. Is there a way to handle the output length of the encrypted message?

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. You should have used a `byte[]`.

Comment: **WARNING** This is absolutely insecure. You are treating a password as a key, and you are using ECB mode to encrypt a plaintext, which is using the platform encoding, which may change. Handling of exceptions is entirely missing. This is taking the shortest route to an insecure solution.

Answer (score 16):

```
package com.ezeon.util.gen;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
/*** Encryption and Decryption of String data; PBE(Password Based Encryption and Decryption)
* @author Vikram
*/
public class CryptoUtil 
{

    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;
    // 8-byte Salt
    byte[] salt = {
        (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32,
        (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03
    };
    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;

    public CryptoUtil() {

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param secretKey Key used to encrypt data
     * @param plainText Text input to be encrypted
     * @return Returns encrypted text
     * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
     * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
     * @throws java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
     * @throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
     *
     */
    public String encrypt(String secretKey, String plainText)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException {
        //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        //Enc process
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        String charSet = "UTF-8";
        byte[] in = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
        byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);
        String encStr = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(out));
        return encStr;
    }

    /**
     * @param secretKey Key used to decrypt data
     * @param encryptedText encrypted text input to decrypt
     * @return Returns plain text after decryption
     * @throws java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
     * @throws javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
     * @throws java.security.InvalidKeyException
     * @throws java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
     * @throws java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
     * @throws javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
     */
    public String decrypt(String secretKey, String encryptedText)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeySpecException,
            NoSuchPaddingException,
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException,
            BadPaddingException,
            IOException {
        //Key generation for enc and desc
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
        // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
        //Decryption process; same key will be used for decr
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        byte[] enc = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(enc);
        String charSet = "UTF-8";
        String plainStr = new String(utf8, charSet);
        return plainStr;
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CryptoUtil cryptoUtil=new CryptoUtil();
        String key="ezeon8547";   
        String plain="This is an important message";
        String enc=cryptoUtil.encrypt(key, plain);
        System.out.println("Original text: "+plain);
        System.out.println("Encrypted text: "+enc);
        String plainAfter=cryptoUtil.decrypt(key, enc);
        System.out.println("Original text after decryption: "+plainAfter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe using `android.util.Base64.decode(str, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);`

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. You should have used a `byte[]`.

Comment: **WARNING** Insecure code! DES and MD5. Why not use a WW2 cipher when you are at it? Then you can successfully protect against toddlers. What about actual exception handling instead of throwing up your hands?

Answer (score 15):

I just want to add that if you want to somehow store the encrypted byte array as String and then retrieve it and decrypt it (often for obfuscation of database values) you can use this approach:

```
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
public class StrongAES 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            String text = "Hello World";
            String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
            // Create key and cipher
            Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            // encrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b: encrypted) {
                sb.append((char)b);
            }

            // the encrypted String
            String enc = sb.toString();
            System.out.println("encrypted:" + enc);

            // now convert the string to byte array
            // for decryption
            byte[] bb = new byte[enc.length()];
            for (int i=0; i<enc.length(); i++) {
                bb[i] = (byte) enc.charAt(i);
            }

            // decrypt the text
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
            String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(bb));
            System.err.println("decrypted:" + decrypted);

        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        StrongAES app = new StrongAES();
        app.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideal solution would be to have intermediate step as base64 encoded string  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5760584/470835

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. You should have used a `byte[]`.

Answer (score 7):

My requirement was to keep the password in a config file in encrypted form and decrypt when the program runs. For this I used the `jasypt` library (`jasypt-1.9.3.jar`). This is a very good library and we can accomplish the task with just 4 lines of code.

First, after adding jar to my project I imported the below library.

```
import org.jasypt.util.text.AES256TextEncryptor;
```

Then I created the below method. I then called this method by passing the text which I need to encrypt in `password` parameter. Using `aesEncryptor.encrypt` method, I encrypted the password which is stored to the `myEncryptedPassword` variable.

```
public void EncryptPassword(String password)
{   
    AES256TextEncryptor aesEncryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    aesEncryptor.setPassword("mypassword");
    String myEncryptedPassword = aesEncryptor.encrypt(password);
    System.out.println(myEncryptedPassword );       
}
```

You might have noticed the method `setPassword` method and the value `mypassword` is used in the above code. This is to make sure that no one can decrypt the password even if they use the encrypted password using the same library.

Now I can see the value in the `myEncryptedPassword` variable something like `h9oJ4P5P8ToRy38wvK11PUQCBrT1oH/zbMWuMrbOlI0rfZrj+qSg6f/u0jctOs/ZUf9t3shiwnEt05/nq8bnag==`. This is the encrypted password. Keep this value in the config file.

I then created the below method to decrypt the password to be used in my program. The value of `passwordFromConfigFile` is the encrypted text which I got from the `EncryptPassword` method. Note that you have to use the same password in the `aesEncryptor.setPassword` method that you used to encrypt the password.

```
public String DecryptPassword(String passwordFromConfigFile)
{           
    AES256TextEncryptor aesEncryptor = new AES256TextEncryptor();
    aesEncryptor.setPassword("mypassword");
    String decryptedPassword = aesEncryptor.decrypt(passwordFromConfigFile);
    return decryptedPassword;   
}
```

The variable `decryptedPassword` will now have the decrypted password value.

Comment: Not too bad. Sadly, jasypt doesn't provide message authentication by default.

Answer (score 4):

The code marked as the solution did not work for me. This was my solution.

```
/*
 * http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptingaStringwithDES.htm
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561104/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-with-my-passphrase-in-java-pc-not-mobile-plat
 */
package encryptiondemo;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


/**
 *
 * @author zchumager
 */
public class EncryptionDemo {

  Cipher ecipher;
  Cipher dcipher;

  EncryptionDemo(SecretKey key) throws Exception {
    ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
  }

  public String encrypt(String str) throws Exception {
    // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
    byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

    // Encrypt
    byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

    // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
    return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
  }

  public String decrypt(String str) throws Exception {
    // Decode base64 to get bytes
    byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);

    byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

    // Decode using utf-8
    return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
  }


    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {

        String data = "Don't tell anybody!";
        String k = "Bar12345Bar12345";

        //SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(k.getBytes(), "AES");
        EncryptionDemo encrypter = new EncryptionDemo(key);

        System.out.println("Original String: " + data);

        String encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(data);

        System.out.println("Encrypted String: " + encrypted);

        String decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Decrypted String: " + decrypted);
    }
}
```

Comment: A think it works better than the other solutions when you have to transport the encrypted data. The code is much simpler too. I just had to change sun.misc.BASE64Encoder and sun.misc.BASE64Decoder for the java.util.Base64 inner classes (Java 8).

Comment: This is insecure code, because you're probably using ECB mode without fully qualifying the cipher, using a string as a key which has reduced entropy and not using a password-based key derivation function, not having message authentication.

Answer (score -2):

Use This This Will work For sure

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class ProtectedConfigFile {

    private static final char[] PASSWORD = "enfldsgbnlsngdlksdsgm".toCharArray();
    private static final byte[] SALT = { (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xde, (byte) 0x33,
            (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0x12, };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String originalPassword = "Aman";
        System.out.println("Original password: " + originalPassword);
        String encryptedPassword = encrypt(originalPassword);
        System.out.println("Encrypted password: " + encryptedPassword);
        String decryptedPassword = decrypt(encryptedPassword);
        System.out.println("Decrypted password: " + decryptedPassword);
    }

    private static String encrypt(String property) throws GeneralSecurityException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
        return base64Encode(pbeCipher.doFinal(property.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    private static String base64Encode(byte[] bytes) {
        // NB: This class is internal, and you probably should use another impl
        return new BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
    }

    private static String decrypt(String property) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSWORD));
        Cipher pbeCipher = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
        pbeCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new PBEParameterSpec(SALT, 20));
        return new String(pbeCipher.doFinal(base64Decode(property)), "UTF-8");
    }

    private static byte[] base64Decode(String property) throws IOException {
        // NB: This class is internal, and you probably should use another impl
        return new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(property);
    }

}
```

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. You should have used a `byte[]`.

Comment: "Use this it will work for sure" is exactly the red flag when I start searching for insecure code, and you didn't disappoint.

Answer (score -3):

Both Encrypt and Decrypt with AES and DES Algoritham ,This worked for me perfectly
    *GithubLink*: [Java Code For Encryption and Decryption](https://github.com/rakesh679/JavaCode/blob/master/DecryptAndEncrypt%20.java)

```
package decrypt;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
/* Decrypt encrypted string into plain string with aes and Des algoritham*/ 

public class Decrypt {

public String decrypt(String str,String k) throws Exception {
// Decode base64 to get bytes

 Cipher  dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(k.getBytes(), "AES");
 dcipher.init(dcipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
//System.out.println(aesKey);
byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
//System.out.println(utf8);
// Decode using utf-8
 return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
 }


  public String encrypt(String str,String k) throws Exception {
 Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
 Key aeskey = new SecretKeySpec(k.getBytes(),"AES");
 byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
 ecipher.init(ecipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskey );

 byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

 return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

}
 public String encrypt(String str,String k,String Algo) throws Exception {
 Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algo);
 Key aeskey = new SecretKeySpec(k.getBytes(),Algo);
 byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
 ecipher.init(ecipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskey );

 byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

 return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

}
public String decrypt(String str,String k,String Algo) throws Exception {
    // Decode base64 to get bytes

     Cipher  dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algo);
     Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(k.getBytes(), Algo);
     dcipher.init(dcipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
    //System.out.println(aesKey);
    byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
    byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
    //System.out.println(utf8);
 // Decode using utf-8
     return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
  }

public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
{
    String original = "rakesh";
    String data = "CfPcX0G+e7TLKKMyyvrvrQ==";
    String k = "qertyuiopasdfghw"; //AES key length must be 16
    String k1 = "qertyuio";  // DES key length must be 8 
    String data1 = "rakesh";
    String data2 = "nAtvNq7uHKE=";
    String Algo= "DES";
    String Algo1= "AES";
    Decrypt decrypter = new Decrypt();
     System.out.println("Original String: " + original);

     System.out.println("encrypted String in DES: " + decrypter.encrypt(data1, 
      k1,Algo));
     System.out.println("Decrypted String in DES: " + decrypter.decrypt(data2, 
       k1,Algo));
     System.out.println("encrypted String in AES: " + decrypter.encrypt(data1, 
      k,Algo1));
     System.out.println("Decrypted String in AES: " + decrypter.decrypt(data, 
      k,Algo1));
   }
}
```

Comment: Other than the string "AES" there is absolutely only trash coding to be found here. First explain what you do and why you default to ECB mode, or why you think that DES is a good option.