# String encoding and decoding in java

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode, password-protection

Currently, I am using java.util.Base64 for encoding and decoding password in java for the USER role.

As I am using java.util.Base64 for user role my requirement is to use other password encoding and decoding for ADMIN role so that by using the database if anyone replaces the USER password to ADMIN password and try to log in for ADMIN they should not get ADMIN access.

So is there any other way in java which supports encoding and decoding string in Java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23561104/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-string-with-my-passphrase-in-java-pc-not-mobile-plat

Comment: Beware that Base64 is **not** encryption and that storing passwords with Base64 does not provide you with any security at all - it's just as secure as storing passwords in plaintext.

Comment: Do you mean you currently identify users by password and not by id/username?

Comment: Or you can use password of Admin to decode your user role string: https://gist.github.com/SimoneStefani/99052e8ce0550eb7725ca8681e4225c5

Comment: @jhamon No. I am using both username and password to identify users. Username is not encoded in the database so everyone can see the admin username and by using their own password that is changed in the ADMIN password column they can log in for ADMIN.

Comment: There are many concerns on your application security. You need more than a base64 encoding to secure the passwords in the database. Currently, it's like you are turning a word from english to spanish and hope people won't understand it. And it seems strange users can get access to the full database table.