# How to encrypt and decrypt folder in android sdcard

Tags: android

is it possible to encrypt the sd card folder r not please help me

if it possible , what is the processor of encryption and decryption

not possible , let me know what can i do for folder security in android sdcard

My file is here :/mnt/sdcard/image1.jpeg.

So How to encrypt this file in android please help me
and Android encryption support MBs r not

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to encrypt the sd card folder r not please help me

Only by modifying the operating system and creating your own custom ROM.

> not possible , let me know what can i do for folder security in android sdcard

If your objective is to allow the user to defend against other people stealing the user's data, you can encrypt individual files as part of how you store them. For example, you could use [SQLCipher for Android](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/) to encrypt a SQLite database that you put on external storage.

If your objective is to hide data from the user, that is implausible. Your encryption algorithm and key will be in your app, which anyone can examine and use to get at the encrypted data. If you do not want users having access to certain pieces of data, do not put that data on the user's device.

Comment: My file is here :/mnt/sdcard/image1.jpeg.

So How to encrypt this file in android please help me and Android encryption support MBs r not

Comment: @yoga: "So How to encrypt this file in android" -- use `javax.crypto` or any other Java encryption option. "Android encryption support MBs r not" -- you might wish to see if there is another Android developer support option available to you in your native language: http://www.andglobe.com.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can encrypt and decrypt the files and folders in your sd card using java libraries. You can implement through  javax.security  package.

Below is the sample of Encryption and Decryption in java

[Example 1](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/EncryptionanddecryptionwithAESECBPKCS7Padding.htm)

[Example2](http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleRSA.html)

[Example 3](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/26020-AES-Decryption-using-key-password-.html)

[Example 4](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/08/24/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-files-in-java-with-aes-in-cbc-mode-using-bouncy-castle-api-and-netbeans-or-eclipse/)

[Take a Look at this Example](http://purejava4all.blogspot.in/2011/04/advanced-encryption-standard-aes.html)

Comment: My file is this :/mnt/sdcard/image1.jpeg. or /mnt/sdcard/Safe

So How to encrypt this file in android please help me and Android encryption support MBs r not

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android