# How to lock Android folder programmatically?

Tags: android, locking, directory

I am making an Android application, and I want to prevent users from opening some folder. In that folder user can store image or video files. It would be great if I could protect that folder with password.

Which is the best way to do that?

Comment: I don't know the best way.. but the easiest (or cheapest) way would be to use your app's private folder (only your app can access) and provide a UI on top of it..

Comment: Cool. But how I can make private folder? Is there any example?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal Every app gets a private folder only that app can access. (Android manages security and it's on internal storage, so not accessible via USB) You can use the above API to manipulate it.

Comment: try this link, it is working fine,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android

le me know.

Answer (score 5):

Here is Both function for encrypt and decrypt file in Sdcard folder. 
we can not lock folder but we can encrypt file using AES in Android, it may help you.

```
static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Here you read the cleartext.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/cleartext");
    // This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/encrypted");

    // Length is 16 byte
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    // Create cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    // Wrap the output stream
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    // Write bytes
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    // Flush and close streams.
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();
}

static void decrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("data/encrypted");

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("data/decrypted");
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

Comment: This is for encrypt and decrypt text file? Is possible to encrypt image or video?

Comment: are you downloading video from server?

Comment: if yes, then you can use this function with input streams.

Comment: try once as per your requirement then you will get perfect result them sure. :)

Comment: No, I want to user allow to record video and store it, but I might download files (including video) from Dropbox, because I want allow user to sync it with Dropbox.

Comment: is it possible to encrypt folders ?

Comment: can we encrypt and decrypt a folder which size is more than 50 GB?

Answer (score 2):

You should save this information on the internal storage. Normally other apps can't access these files. From the quideliness:

> You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

See the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: So, as I get from this link, I just need to save application files into some folder on the internal storage, and that will be private?

Comment: Yep, but don't forget the Private Mode: FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Also be aware that rooted devices might be able to access these files.

Answer (score 1):

Insted of LOCK i will saggest you make folder with `.` like foldername -> `.test`

user cant see that folder here is code

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/.test");

   if(!direct.exists())
    {
        if(direct.mkdir()) 
          {
           //directory is created;
          }

    }
```

above code is create folder with name ".test" (in SD CARD) then save your data(file, video.. whatever) in this folder user cant access it.

**if you create folder in internal storage then if user clear data of your app then that folder may `EMPTY`!**

Comment: What I get by creating .test ?

Comment: What if the user views that SD-Card on the computer using SD-Card reader? Even if the folder is hidden there, the user can enable `View Hidden files and folders` options in the windows and will see the files. It's not a good security.

Comment: How  to do that one?

Comment: but .test folder access in windows then how is it safe?

Comment: @NripendraOjha you can use file encryption for that. please check https://medium.com/@w.g.sandaru/how-to-encrypt-files-in-android-devices-43f1e543f4c3

Comment: If i have total 250 video files (files size minimum 50 GB) then how  encryption will be good idea?

Comment: @NripendraOjha could you explain use of that files?? or just want to store it?

Comment: @DhavalParmar sir, I want to give offline video courses in pendrive for rural area student, where internet is not working properly, and it play only on android mobile.