# Create secure data-locker android app.

Tags: android, file, security, open-source, viewer

Create secure data locker for security purposes .

I don't want files in that folder to be opened by other viewers available.

I want my native pdf viewer to be used every time i access that specific folder.

**Datalocker** app will use opensource android pdf viewer. Data locker app can use internal storage only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question what I understood is,

1. App need to store pdf file securely.
2. Use internal storage as preference.

**1.** Use secure encryption/decryption algorithms like **AES-256 with password based cryptographic key**.
   Also **code obfuscation & jumble algorithms** can be applied for secure key generation to avoid reverse engineering attacks upto a level.

**2.** For Internal storage of application you can change **android:installLocation="internalOnly"** in manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="string"
          android:sharedUserId="string"
          android:sharedUserLabel="string resource" 
          android:versionCode="integer"
          android:versionName="string"
          android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    . . .
</manifest>
```

For more info please refer [**this question & answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android)