# how i can hidden the pdf file in External Storage Directory in android appliction

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

Hi Guys i have craeted a application for Book Reading.
in this project the the user can download the book from friebase and stored them in the External Storage.
The user Can only View the book with this application.
i don't want to show the user book in External Storage.
I Store them in hidden way. Tell me is there is any libaray or any way to stored pdf book  them in hidden.

Comment: Define what you mean by external storage.  Do you mean a removable SD card?  Then no.  Do you mean external storage by the android definition (which is really just internal to the phone)?  Then every app gets a private directory in external storage, and no other app can read it.  Of course if they root the phone they can do it anyway, nothing can stop that.

Comment: please refer [How to encrypt file from SD card using AES in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782187/how-to-encrypt-file-from-sd-card-using-aes-in-android)