# IllegalArgumentException ChaCha20 requires 128 bit or 256 bit key

Tags: java, android, string, encryption, byte

> How could I convert String to 128 or 256 bit key for chacha20 Encryption .

```
    ChaCha20Encryptor chaCha20Encryptor = new ChaCha20Encryptor();
    byte[] data = chaCha20Encryptor.encrypt(plaintext.getBytes(),key2.getBytes());
    String enStr = BaseUtilityHelper.encodeBase64URLSafeString(data);
    encryptedTv.setText(enStr);
```

**ChaCha20Encryptor**

```
public class ChaCha20Encryptor implements Encryptor {

    private final byte randomIvBytes[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] randomKeyBytes) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidCipherTextException {

        ChaChaEngine cipher = new ChaChaEngine();
        cipher.init(true, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(randomKeyBytes), randomIvBytes));

        byte[] result = new byte[data.length];
        cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] randomKeyBytes)
            throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException,
            IllegalStateException, InvalidCipherTextException {

        ChaChaEngine cipher = new ChaChaEngine();
        cipher.init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(randomKeyBytes), randomIvBytes));

        byte[] result = new byte[data.length];
        cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, result, 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getKeyLength() {
        return 32;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChaCha20()";
    }
}
```

where

```
private String key2 = "19920099-564A-4869-99B3-363F8145C0BB";
private String plaintext = "Hello";
```

I have also tried different keys. but it requires key2 to convert it to 128 or 256 bits.  I have searched on SO. and find some links

[Java 256-bit AES Password-Based Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption)

[Turn String to 128-bit key for AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22410602/turn-string-to-128-bit-key-for-aes)

but these doesn't look like relevant to my requirement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hash a password in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860943/how-can-i-hash-a-password-in-java)

Comment: If `key2` was generated with very good randomness and has no internal structure beside the dashes then a simple hash might be enough to get a 128 bit key.

Answer (score 0):

Your key, without the dashes, is a perfectly valid 128 bits hexadecimal key. It is 32 characters, which is 16 bytes => 128 bits.

All you have to do is :

1. remove the dashes `key2.replace("-","");`
2. Convert the hexadecimal String to its byte[] representation. I personally use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` available for java 1.7 and above. Use it like this : `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hexString);`

Your complete call should look  like this :

```
chaCha20Encryptor.encrypt(
             plaintext.getBytes(),
             DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(key2.replace("-","")));
```

Comment: I don't have latest java 1.7 . Is there any  other alternate. I can't test it right now

Comment: There are also alternatives using apache common librairies using Hex object. There is also a solution using Google guava (but i never used it).